# Change State to EntityState.Modified raised error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have the following Asp.Net MVC 4 scaffold code.

```
    //
    // POST: /Detail/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Detail detail)
    {
        var dd = Details.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DetailId == detail.DetailId);
        if (dd == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        detail.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        detail.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = detail.MasterId });
        }
        return View(dealDetail);
    }
```

However, the line `_db.Entry(detail).State = EntityState.Modified;` raise the following error. What's the correct way to update the detail line of a master/detail editing scenery?

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var dd = Details.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DetailId == detail.DetailId);
```

will cause loading of Detail entity from the database. Now you have two Details with the same Id but only one (the one loaded by that query) can be used for persistence. You can change your code to:

```
if (!Details.Any(d => d.DetailId == detail.DetailId))
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

or update the attached detail (`dd`) for example by:

```
// All values of detail entity must be set in your HTTP post! 
_db.Entry(dd).CurrentValues.SetValues(detail);
```